# How to set storage rules so I can run my Firebase storage emulator?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-admin, firebase-cli, firebase-tools

When I run `firebase emulators:start` I have this error

> Error: Cannot start the Storage emulator without rules file specified
> In firebase.json

Before installing Storage emulator, I can set the rule for Firestore like this

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "./functions/firestore.rules"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "storage": {
      "port": 9199
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

I believe I have to set the rule for storage in here. But I don't know how. I can't find the docs for this

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The error you're seeing is caused by a missing storage rules file. The solution is very similar to the way you set rules for Firestore.

1. Create a file called `storage.rules` in the same directory as firebase.json.
2. Add the following lines to it:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

3. Specify the rules file for the storage emulator in your firebase.json:

```
"emulators": {
  "storage": {
    "port": 9199,
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
}
```

Now, it's ready to start emulators.

### Update

Thank you everyone for warning about the change in the newer versions. With the latest version, `storage.rules` should be defined at the top level in your firebase.json:

```
"emulators": {
  "storage": {
    "port": 9199
  },
},
"storage": {
  "rules": "storage.rules"
}
```

Comment: With the latest version I had to place `storage/rules` not within `emulators/storage`, but at the top level in `firebase.json`.

Comment: @PeterKoltai I also needed to do that. Thanks.

Comment: For me the  "rules": "storage.rules" entry had to be placed in the top level place in the firebase.json file, not within the "emulators" entry but in the "storage"